# how to avoid error during viewing img in datagridview when image is not added by the user

Tags: c#, mysql

This is my code for my datagridview to view the image

```
                Byte[] img1 = (Byte[])stud_tbl.CurrentRow.Cells[11].Value;
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(img1);
                picturebox_student.Image = Image.FromStream(ms
```

Now my problem is that

1. I should always require the user to input all the data including the img which is not appropriate

```
            if (stud_idtf.Text.Length == 0 || name_tf.Text.Length == 0 || gender_tf.Text.Length == 0 || course_tf.Text.Length == 0 || yr_tf.Text.Length == 0 || vio_tf.Text.Length == 0 || taken_cb.Text.Length == 0 || manual_tf.Text.Length == 0 || report_tf.Text.Length == 0 || date_tf.Text.Length == 0 || picturebox_student.Image == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: Please dont leave any fields blank!");
                prompt = 0;
            }
```

> So then if I wouldn't restrict user to input the the data im having this error "Parameter is not Valid" which is obviously right because in the datagridview there is a cell that is empty.

**Is there any way to prevent this? I just want it not to restrict user to inputting img and not causing error during view in datagridview.**

[Without image data input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAlxy.png)

[With image data input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMcqp.png)

> Once there's atleast one data without picture the error will occur.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking… _”I should always require the user to input all the data including the img which is not appropriate”_ … ? makes no sense. You need to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65210348/edit) your question and clarify what you are asking. Where is the error “parameter is not valid” coming from? Do you want to require the user to add a picture or not?

Comment: @JohnG mybad umm its hard to explain like im sure about the terminologies but anyways, i want the user to choose either if he wants to add or not. Now, if the user has added a new data that contains picture it displays well in datagridview and then when the user has added a data which do not contain picture that's where error occurred its says Parameter is not valid because in the data recorded in datagridview has a picture then the second one doesnt have so that it.

Comment: You might want to explain this with an example. You stated that… _”i want the user to choose either if he wants to add or not.”_ … how is the user able to “choose” this add or not add? There is no posted code that shows where a new image is added to the grid, so we can only guess. From what I can decipher, is that if the user does NOT select an image, the error happens. I can only assume the code is possibly passing a null value? Without the code, speculation is all you will get.

Comment: I suggest you peruse the SO [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) section as it shows how SO works. The [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may help. In addition, you may find the SO [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) section useful.

Comment: The only thing in the posted code I can see that may throw an exception is if the cell “Value” at column 11 is `null`… `Byte[] img1 = (Byte[])stud_tbl.CurrentRow.Cells[11].Value;` … if `img1` is `null`, then you will get an `ArgumentNullException` on the next line of code when it tries to create the stream from the `null` `img1`… `MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(img1);` … In any case you need to check and make sure `stud_tbl.CurrentRow.Cells[11].Value` is NOT `null` BEFORE the code attempts to create the stream.

Comment: @JohnG ohh now i get it so what im thinking right now is that i will assign a default picture "no image" so that whenever they will not add picture that default picture will be save so it wont pass as null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An if check will solve your problem

```
Byte[] img1 = (Byte[])stud_tbl.CurrentRow.Cells[11].Value;
if(img1.Length != 0){
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(img1);
    picturebox_student.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
}
```

Comment: I didn't think of that. That was easy i also tried to set a default picture in which if the user didn't add image that default image will be save.